# Set focus on dynamic list (Angularjs way)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have input what change value of 'validaTag' when user press '/' (like a # on instagram).

I want set focus on first element on this list and blur on input.

**Model**

```
                        <input type="text"  name="myAddress" ng-enter="chatCtrl.sendMsg(chatCtrl[tab]); chatCtrl[tab]=''; " ng-click="chatCtrl.getChatTab(tab);" ng-model="chatCtrl[tab]" class="input-chat" style="width: 95%" ng-change="checkkey(chatCtrl[tab])" >

                        <div ng-hide="!validaTag">
                            <ul class="list-group tags_chat">
                                <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="enviarTexto(tag.descricao, tab)" ng-repeat="tag in alltags | filter:hashtag:strict | limitTo : 3" setFocus="$last">
                                    <b >{{tag.tag}}</b> -
                                    {{tag.descricao}}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>


                    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  $scope.checkkey = function (text) {
    $scope.hashtag = '';
    $scope.alltags = '';
    $scope.frase = '';

    $scope.validaTag = text.includes('/');
    $scope.frase = text.substr(0, text.indexOf('/'));

    if($scope.validaTag == true){
      $scope.hashtag = text.substring(text.indexOf("/"))
      $.ajax({url:'blablabla',
      async: !1,
      type: "GET"
    }).done(function(response) {
            response = evalJson(response);
            $scope.alltags = response;
            $scope.alltags = $.map($scope.alltags, function(value, index) {
            return [value];
          });
        })
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the template you are showing is a directive template and if you only have one occurrence of  in the directive then something like this should do the trick

```
angular.element(element.find('li')[0]).focus();
```

if that doesn't work you may will need to implement your own directive for this.